# image slider, position will not reset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a simple image slider for the landing page of a website. There are two effects taking place. First, the image transitions by fading the current one in and the subsequent one out, using setInterval. There are also arrow buttons that, when clicked, slide the images forward or backward. The fading is working just fine, but the sliding functions are leaving the images in the offscreen position. Here are:

```
function slidePrevPic(dur){

    var currentPic = $('.active-pic');
    var prevPic = currentPic.prev();
    if(prevPic.length == 0){
        prevPic = $('#pics img').last();
    }

    $('.arrow').css('pointer-events','none');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.arrow').css('pointer-events','auto');
    },dur);

    w = $(window).width();
    prevPic.css('opacity',.4);
    prevPic.css('left',-w);
    prevPic.animate({
        'left': 0
        }, dur);
    currentPic.animate({
        'left': w
        }, dur);
    setTimeout(function(){
        currentPic.css('left',0);
        currentPic.css('opacity',0);
    },dur);

    prevPic.addClass('active-pic');
    currentPic.removeClass('active-pic');
};

function slideNextPic(dur){

    var currentPic = $('.active-pic');
    var nextPic = currentPic.next();
    if(nextPic.length == 0){
        nextPic = $('#pics img').first();
    }

    $('.arrow').css('pointer-events','none');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.arrow').css('pointer-events','auto');
    },dur);

    w = $(window).width();
    nextPic.css('opacity',.4);
    nextPic.css('left',w);
    nextPic.animate({
        'left':0
        },dur);
    currentPic.animate({
        'left':-w
    },dur);
    setTimeout(function(){
        currentPic.css('left',0);
        currentPic.css('opacity',0);
    },dur);

    nextPic.addClass('active-pic');
    currentPic.removeClass('active-pic');
};
```

I was trying to simplify everything to figure out what was wrong, so instead of hiding and showing images or fading them in and out, I'm just animating and setting the opacity. The idea here is pretty simple. All of the pictures are in the same place and all but one have 0 opacity. When the slider is called, the next image is moved offscreen, the current and next image are animated together (moving the current image offscreen), then the position of the current image should be reset. The sliding effect is working well, but the position of the current image is not reset, so that when it cycles back the image space goes white. I am still generally confused about how the timing of function execution with jquery and js is managed, so any help in that general direction is also much appreciated. Also, here is the code that calls these functions:

```
var picInterval = setInterval(function(){
    fadeNextPic(picFadeTime);
},idleTime);

$('#banner #right-arrow').click(function(){
    clearInterval(picInterval);
    slideNextPic(picSlideTime);
    picInterval = setInterval(function(){
        fadeNextPic(picFadeTime);
    },idleTime);
});

$('#banner #left-arrow').click(function(){
    clearInterval(picInterval);
    slidePrevPic(picSlideTime);
    picInterval = setInterval(function(){
        fadeNextPic(picFadeTime);
    },idleTime);
});
```

Comment: Could you post it on jsFiddle? And please include the HTML and if necessary CSS?

Comment: do you need to reinvent the wheel? there are quite a few carousels out there that you can drop in and use. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: Yeah I could definitely just use bootstrap, but I'm trying to get better at managing jquery events and I figured it would be worth it to knock my head against it a little.